# How to concatMap over all key/value pairs in an Aeson.Object using lenses

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

I've been fooling around with the combinators in Control.Lens.Indexed, especially [`iconcatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#v:iconcatMap), but I haven't been able to come-up with a function with the following type-sig using the [`Data.Aeson.Lens.members`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/lens-aeson-1.0.2/Data-Aeson-Lens.html#v:members) lens:

```
func 

  -- list of key/value pairs, essentially
  :: Aeson.Object                  

  -- function for the concatMap operation to which the 
  -- key (Text) and value is passed
  -> (Text -> Aeson.Value -> [a])  

  -- resultant concatenated list
  -> [a]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired function is [`iconcatMapOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#g:6). Also, note that `members` traverses types with `AsValue` instance, and there's no such instance for `Object`, so we need to wrap it to `Value`.

```
import qualified Data.Aeson as Aeson
import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import Data.Text

func :: Aeson.Object -> (Text -> Aeson.Value -> [a]) -> [a]
func obj f = iconcatMapOf members f (Aeson.Object obj)
```

Comment: would you be kind enough to explain the difference between `iconcatMap` and `iconcatMapOf`?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda `iconcatMap` folds over a data structure using the `FoldableWithIndex` instance. `iconcatMapOf` folds over a structure, but you can  additionally specify the way of folding, using an indexed traversal (a getter here concretely). So, using `iconcatMapOf`, you can fold in reversed order, or any order, or just some elements, by giving specifying a different traversal, while with `iconcatMap`, you can only fold in the default way (given by the class instance).

Comment: In this case, `Object` and `Value` don't have `FoldableWithIndex` instances, (they don't have the right kind to begin with), so you can only fold them with a custom fold.