# How to "rearrange" an Aeson.Object using lenses?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

It seems I [keep getting stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553510/how-to-concatmap-over-all-key-value-pairs-in-an-aeson-object-using-lenses) whenever I reach out for lenses to transform some JSON.

After parsing this into an `Aeson.Value`...

```
{
  "action": {
    "action": "reply",
    "replies": [
      "Does this work?",
      "What about this?"
    ]
  },
  "suggestions": [...],
  "inputs": [...]
}
```

...I'm trying to transform it into...

```
{
  "action": "reply",
  "replies": [
    "Does this work?",
    "What about this?"
  ]
  "suggestions": [...],
  "inputs": [...]
}
```

Basically I'm trying to bring all keys-value pairs nested inside the top-level `action`-key to the top-level itself, and finally remove the top-level `action` key. (Note, there is a nested `action` key inside the top-level `action` key -- it is not a typo).

Answer (score 2):

Using lenses from the `lens-aeson` package, I guess what you want is something like:

```
Object $ (x ^. _Object & sans "action") <> (x ^. key "action"._Object)
```

Here, `sans` comes from `Control.Lens.At` and removes the top-level `"action"`, leaving an `Object` (i.e., `HashMap Text Value`) with the remaining top-level keys.  The `key "action"._Object` getter selects the top-level `"action"` value and extracts an `Object`.  The two `Object`s can be concatenated using `<>` and wrapped into a `Value` with the `Object` constructor.

Full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module AesonLens where

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Lens     -- from lens-aeson
import Control.Lens

ex1 :: IO Value
ex1 = do Just val <- decodeFileStrict "aesonlens.json"
         return val

main = do
  x <- ex1
  print $ Object $ (x ^. _Object & sans "action") <> (x ^. key "action"._Object)
```

with input file `"aesonlens.json"`:

```
{
  "action": {
    "action": "reply",
    "replies": [
      "Does this work?",
      "What about this?"
    ]
  },
  "suggestions": [1,2,3],
  "inputs": [4,5,6]
}
```

yields:

```
> main
Object (fromList [("inputs",Array [Number 4.0,Number 5.0,Number 6.0]),
("action",String "reply"),("replies",Array [String "Does this work?",
String "What about this?"]),("suggestions",Array [Number 1.0,Number 2.0,
Number 3.0])])
```

Comment: IIUC, this is not _really_ operating on the `Aeson.Value`. The core operations are being done on the underlying `HashMap` and in the end it is converted back into `Aeson.Value` by using the `Aeson.Object` constructor. Right?

Comment: What if `Aeson.Value` had an instance of the [At](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/lens-4.16.1/Control-Lens-At.html#t:At) typeclass use by the [sans](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/lens-4.16.1/Control-Lens-At.html#v:sans) operator? It would make this more "direct", right?

Comment: Also, is there an easy way to find a lens operator that does X? For example, how did you discover the `sans` operator? A follow-up question could be, is there a lens operator to add a key/value to a map-like data-structure? i.e. the opposite of `sans`?